# Java Provided Observable not a good practice

Tags: java, design-patterns, observable, observer-pattern

```
public void update(Observable obs, Object arg) 
{
  if (obs instanceof WeatherData) {
  WeatherData weatherData = (WeatherData)obs;
  this.temperature = weatherData.getTemperature();
  this.humidity = weatherData.getHumidity();
  display();
  }
 }
```

The above piece of code is from *Head First Design Patterns*. An event is going to fire for every change that occurs, and this will be sent to all the observers whether the event is what they expect or not. The `if` block helps in letting the code decide which events to handle.

So create observable for every such scenario will be a good practice right?

Comment: `java.util.Observable` is deprecated since Java 9 …

Comment: @tquadrat, while the Java implementation is deprecated, the [pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer) itself remains very useful. Java simply didn't do a good job of implementing it.

Comment: @jaco0646: I have no doubt that the Pattern is extremely useful, but when the question is whether creating `Observable` is a good practice (with an explicit reference to the class in the sample), it must be allowed to say that this class is deprecated. The question was *not only* regarding the pattern …

Comment: @tquadrat, there is no `import` statement in the sample. It could be `my.custom.Observable`.

Comment: @jaco0646: Confessed, but I know the book Anshul refers to ("*Head First Design Patterns*"), and they use `java.util.Observable` with exact the code he provided in the question …

Comment: Well, in that case, [Observer is deprecated in Java 9. What should we use instead of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380073/observer-is-deprecated-in-java-9-what-should-we-use-instead-of-it)

Answer (score 1):

> So create observable for every such scenario will be a good practice right?

Yes! I have advocated this approach numerous times, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946153/1371329), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60152845/1371329), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493514/1371329). It perplexes me why people so often implement the Observer pattern with only one event class and then struggle to pass different types of events. By all means: create new event classes!